# SSL multiple subdomains Your connection is not private

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, subdomain

I have a web application with nginx. I would like to have unlimited subdomains. When I open subdomain.domain.com I see in my Chrome:

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from subdomain.domain.com (for example,     passwords, messages, or credit cards).

Back to safetyAdvanced
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

I can't understand how to fix this issue. I should add another SSL cert for all subdomains or I need different cert for every subdomain? Can someone explain what is the correct flow here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A [wildcard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) SSL certificate would allow you to have unlimited subdomains with a single certificate.